# I am getting an error line 25, col 30. Expression cannot be assigned

Tags: trigger

i.e at `"Account ac = peronAccountList1.get(sc.AccountId);"`

//******** Service Contract *******//

```
public class ServiceContractTriggerHelper {

    public static void updateAddress(List<ServiceContract> src){

        Set<ID> acclist = new Set<ID>();

        Id rectype = Schema.SObjectType.ServiceContract.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Medical Alert Service').getRecordTypeId();

        for(ServiceContract sc: src){
            acclist.add(sc.AccountId);
        }

        Map<Id,Account> peronAccountList1 = new Map<Id,Account>();
        List<Account> aclst =  [Select Id,Is_Active_Shipping_Address__c,Is_Active_Alternate_Address__c,Alternate_City__c,Alternate_Country__c,
                                Township_Borough_Municipality_B__c,Township_Borough_Municipality_S__c,Active__c,CustomerPriority__c,Language__c,Match_Billing_Address__c,
                                NumberofLocations__c,SLA__c,SLAExpirationDate__c,SLASerialNumber__c,State_Province__c,UpsellOpportunity__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :acclist];

        for(Integer i=0; i<aclst.size(); i++){
            peronAccountList1.put(aclst[i].id,aclst[i]);
        }
        for(ServiceContract sc: src){
            Account ac = peronAccountList1.get(sc.AccountId);
            if(accIdwithlist.get(sc.AccountId)!=null && sc.RecordType = rectype){
                if(ac.Is_Active_Shipping_Address__c){
                    sc.City__c = ac.Alternate_City__c;
                    sc.Country__c = ac.Alternate_Country__c;
                    sc.Township_Borough_Municipality__c = ac.Township_Borough_Municipality_S__c;
                }

                if(ac.Is_Active_Alternate_Address__c){
                    sc.City__c = ac.Alternate_City__c;
                    sc.Country__c = ac.Alternate_Country__c;
                    sc.Township_Borough_Municipality__c = ac.Township_Borough_Municipality_S__c;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is where your title (edited into question) suggests.

I believe this:

```
if(accIdwithlist.get(sc.AccountId)!=null && sc.RecordType = rectype){
```

should be changed to this

```
if(accIdwithlist.get(sc.AccountId)!=null && sc.RecordType == rectype){
```

Single `=` is assignment 
Double `==` is equality comparison

Comment: Actually it is showing error in "Account ac = peronAccountList1.get(sc.AccountId);"  this line

Comment: @PriyaMukherjee - Maybe your code you are looking at is off from the running code. I do not believe that that line as written in your question would throw that error. Try changing what I said and see if the error persists.

Comment: @PriyaMukherjee - Since you are new here When you ask a question and receive answers you can up vote them t indicate they were helpful or well written. If an answer solves your issue, you can mark it as the accepted answer. Marking as accepted is not mandatory but is encouraged as it does help others looking for similar issues to find answers

Comment: Okay surely I will follow as said.